# No longer able to see option to enable domain-wide delegation of authority for google service account

Tags: google-oauth, google-workspace, service-accounts

I want to enable G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority for a new service account. I already had enabled it for one service account a few weeks back. While creating the new service account, I no longer see the option to `Enable Google Apps Domain-wide Delegation`. I am following these steps: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account.
I can't even see that option for the older service account when I click on `Edit` for that service account

I was already able to do it for one service account, although I no longer see the option to disable/enable it when I click on Edit

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56225798/3275273.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see the checkbox, it means you don't need to enable it. You can get the client ID from the UI or by looking at the JSON private key you downloaded, and use that to authorize your scopes in the Admin console.