# Domain-wide delegation alternative Google Workspace service account

Tags: google-oauth, google-workspace, service-accounts

EDIT: We cannot enable domain wide delegation.

I understand a form of this question has been asked and answered at least twice now:

[No longer able to see option to enable domain-wide delegation of authority for google service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451474/no-longer-able-to-see-option-to-enable-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority-for-g)

[Google G-Suite API Console not showing Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56225798/3275273)

But no solution was given for getting this to work without being able to enable domain wide delegation and I can find NO useful documentation for the process. Can someone help me out with where to look or with the process itself?

Our use: We currently have a web app dealer management software (DMS) built in .NET. Using Microsoft's EWS API we implemented the ability for a service account to reach across and read and send email on behalf of a user through our app, essentially impersonating that user. We had the same functionality working in Google on a Workspace account that had the ability to enable Domain wide delegation. Now we are setting up a new dealer to use this same functionality, but their Workspace account is missing this feature. How can I get this same functionality working again without domain wide delegation?

We haven't really tried anything because we can't find any documentation from Google. We have a service account created and an OAuth2 credential created.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation

Comment: Thank you, but this does not help. As indicated, I no longer have the Domain wide delegation panel.

Comment: Are you sure you are admin?  You need to be the admin to configure delegation

Answer (score 0):

You need to have admin access on a google workspace domain to configure delegation

[image]

then on that page

[image]

The location hasn't changed if your not seeing it my guess would be your not the admin.

Comment: Turns out this was the problem. Dealer claimed we were super admin, but clearly we are not. Working on establishing correct permissions. I unfortunately went down a two day rabbit hole as I got confused by the threads I linked in my original post.