# Unable to check "Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation" in GSuite

Tags: google-workspace, service-accounts

I am trying to setup a service account to get delegation from a GSuite admin. The manual says I have to first check "Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation" option in the service account, but my checkbox is disabled.

[image]

Why does this happen and what should I do to make it work?

---

This is different with another question:  [Google G-Suite API Console not showing Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56225798/google-g-suite-api-console-not-showing-enable-g-suite-domain-wide-delegation)

I can see the checkbox, but it is disabled.

Answer (score 9):

I had to click "Edit" on top of the screen button to make changes. It was really stupid.

Comment: Thank you for this as I was confused as well. I guess it's bad UX on Google's part.